# Aplicar Drag a un elemento hijo sin que se mueva el padre (ambos tienen la propiedad draggable)

Tags: html5, drag-and-drop

estoy usando la API de el drag and drop de HTML5. Resulta que tengo una serie de divs a las que les aplico el drag and drop. Y funciona bien!. Ahora, cada una de esas divs tienen otros divs hijas a las cuales tambien tengo que aplicarles el drag and drop, pero cuando tomo en drag cualquiera de las divs hijas se viene el padre completo. necesito que cuando le aplique drag a un hijo, al padre no se le aplique. ¿Alguien ya lo ha hecho?. Saludos y gracias de antemano!

Comment: hola Bienvenido a [es.SO], te invito a que hagas el [tour] y de paso te invito a leer [ask] para que mejores tus preguntas, de ser posible agrega también un [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Hola y Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te aconsejo que mejores el título de tu pregunta, añadas ejemplos, etc; con el objetivo de hacerte entender más fácilmente. Sigue los enlaces dejados por JuankGlezz y asi tendrás más oportunidad que las personas que conforman la comunidad puedan ayudarte con tu pregunta. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

En principio deberías de usar el método stopPropagation() Para evitar que el padre sea arrastrado también.

```
element.addEventListener(‘dragstart’, function (evt) {
evt.stopPropagation();
... 
}
```